# Nodejs Mongodb server connection issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-modules

I am trying to connect to the mongodb database using Nodejs - express. The program is working properly and i am getting the query and html output. But when I make the query again the program is not connecting to mongodb database. I have to run the program again (node command) to get the connection. I want the command to be made everytime the post query is given.

Given below is the code

**Server.js**

```
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let Util = require('./files/modules/acessdb');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    
    res.send("Working");
});

app.post('/getinput',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("Options ="+req.body.depart);

    let data = Util.getdata(req.body.depart,res);
    console.log("Data = ",data);

   // res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});

const server = app.listen(8000,()=>{
    let host=server.address().address;
    let port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server running at "+host+":"+port);
});
```

**accessdb.js**

```
function getdata(data,res){
    conn.stconnect((err)=>{
        if(err)
        throw err;
    });

    let html = "<html> <head> </head> <body> <table>";

    const db = conn.getdb;
    const collection = db().collection('Students');
    console.log("Server entered");
        val = async ()=>{
            try{
            let file = await collection.find({"Department":data}).toArray()
            console.log("data is ",file);

            console.log("Data here : ",data);

            console.log("Type = "+file.length);

            for(let i =0;i<file.length;i++){

               html+="<tr> <td> "+file[i].Name+"</td><td>"+file[i].Department+"</td><td>"+file[i].Semester;
               html+="</td></tr>";
                console.log("FIle :"+file[i].Name)

            }
            html+="</table></body>";

            

            res.send(html);
        }
        catch(e){
            throw e;
        }
        finally{
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
   let value = val();
}
module.exports = {getdata};
```

**connect.js**

```
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
let client;
let dbname = 'College';
var db;

async function stconnect(callback){ 
     
    client = new MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
     db= client.db(dbname);
    
}

const getdb = ()=> db;

const disconnect = () =>client.close();

stconnect()
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("Server connected");
        return ;
    })
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(()=>{
    });

module.exports ={stconnect,getdb,disconnect};
```

### Update

I got the program to work but am having some issues.
Here are the changes I made.
1)added seperate fetch conditions for connect and disconnect. (Working but the issues said below
2)added the await option (got it working)

**Issues**
1)The program connects automatically to server even without the fetch request for connect. I only want the connection to be made during the fetch request. Once the connection is made the disconnect and connect buttons work properly

2)TypeError: Failed to fetch. This error is coming when i click the button linked with the fetch command. The fetch does work since i can see that the queries i sent are working during connection and not working during disconnection.

3)`throw new error_1.MongoNotConnectedError('Client must be connected before running operations');` 
The program exits when i try to access the database while disconnected. I want the server to keep running and just display the error message. I tried adding .catch but it is not working.

**fetch**

```
con.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    
    console.log("Button clicked");
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/login',{method:'GET'})
        .then(()=>{
            // if(response.ok){
            // console.log("client connected");
            // alert("Connected");
            // return;}
            
            // throw new Error("Connection error");
            document.getElementById("status").value = "Connected";
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log("Could not connect");
        });
        
        
});

let discon = document.getElementById("ddb");
discon.addEventListener('click',e=>{

    console.log("Discon clicked");

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/disconnect',{method:'GET'})
        .then((response)=>{
            if(response.ok){
                console.log("client disconnected");
                alert("Disconnected");
                return;
            }
            throw new Error("Disconnection error");
            document.getElementById("status").value = "Disconnected";
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log("Could not connect");
        });
        
});
```

**functions**

```
app.get('/disconnect',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("Entered disconnect");
    Util.removeconnection(); //Util is the imported module which contains the below function
})

async function removeconnection(){
    await conn.disconnect();
    // console.log("Entered");
}


app.get('/login',function login(req,res){

    console.log("Entered connect");

    Util.getconnection();

})


async function getconnection(){
    await conn.stconnect((err)=>{
        if(err)
        console.log("Connection error")
    });

}

getconnection()
    .catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ` throw new error_1.MongoNotConnectedError('Client must be connected before running operations');`
                  ^

MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations

Comment: Just keep the connection open. Drop this nonsense connecting/disconnecting stuff after each query/page load. BTW: You dont await in dbaccess for "stconnect". And you mix promises with callbacks, which is bad practice.

Comment: @Marc Yeah that was what i was told. I just did this to understand how the await function works. I normally do callbacks. I am trying out promises now. I don't fully understand it so for some parts I did callback for ease.
Yeah I added the await in the update part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `accessdb.js` file, in the try-catch block, remove the `finally` part.

```
try{
  ...
    }
    catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
 // remove the finally block
 let value = val();
```

After successfully executing the `try-catch` block, `finally` block is executed which in your case closes the database connection.

Edit: As the OP clarified that the connection to the database has to be reset at every request, so you are required to wait until the connection to the database has been completed.

So make `getData` function asynchronous, and add `await` to `conn.stconnect` in access accessdb.js file.

```
async function getdata(data,res){
  await conn.stconnect((err)=>{
    if(err)
    throw err;
...
```

Comment: It works. But i do want it to disconnect. I want the connection to be made everytime a post request is sent. Once the request is processed, I want the connection to close.

Comment: @JustaNobody Then you have to connect again. Are you connecting again?

Comment: I added a call to stconnect in the function in connect.js. When the post query is called it should go to conenct.js. Then won't the stconnect get executed? stconnect contains the code for connection. [Note:- I also tried adding data as parameter and empty function]

Comment: @JustaNobody When you make a second connection to the database, you are not waiting for connection to complete. You have to somehow wait until the connection is made.

Comment: K so should i use await? Where should i add it?

Comment: @JustaNobody You can make getData function asynchronous and await conn.stconnect

Comment: K I will check it out

Comment: @JustaNobody Just wondering, were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But the program did not work for me. The issue still persisted. I made some changes to the code. I will add it to edited message in the question so you can review it and correct the mistakes I made.

Comment: Hey I made the update post. I didn't have the code with me so wasn't able to update sooner. 1 and 3 are issues I can't figure. 2 is something I am experimenting with.